# Отличие моделей Span<char> и string в памяти?

Tags: c#, строки

Одна и та же строка в Span представлена как последовательный набор заполненных ячеек значений символов, а в string - как случайно разбросанные по памяти ячейки со значениями символов?

Comment: span в себе ничего не хранит, он лишь ссылается на строку. можете в голове держать, что он содержит ссылку на строку, начало и конец среза. предок `Span<T>` - `ArraySegment<T>`

Comment: Span сразу идёт хэш, из-за чего не занимает места в памяти. + Код быстрее работает

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду под "сразу идёт хэш"? Поясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка - это ссылка на неизменяемую непрерывную область памяти, которая содержит:

- длина строки 4 байта = N
- N символов, каждый 2 байта

То есть утверждение

> случайно разбросанные по памяти ячейки

неверно.

`Span<char>` - это структура, которая хранит свою длину и ссылку на некую область памяти. То есть там где данные у спана, там нет информации о длине, длина и ссылка на начало данных хранятся в самом спане.

Еще есть нюанс, так как строка - это немутабельная структура данных, `Span<char>` не может ссылаться на `string`. На `string` может ссылаться только `ReadOnlySpan<char>`.

Спаны используют для того, чтобы избежать лишнего копирования данных в памяти, то есть чаще всего для оптимизаций кода. Так что если на данный момент вас устраивает производительность и потребление памяти приложением, то вам рано задумываться о спанах.

Например, здесь не произойдет копирование данных в памяти, спан будет читать данные из того же участка памяти, что и строка.

```
string text = "hello world";
ReadOnlySpan<char> span = text.AsSpan()[0..5]; // [ 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' ]
```

Если бы вы сделали вот так, то копирование данных произойдет.

```
string hello = text.Remove(5); // "hello"
```

Строка `hello` - ссылка на новый объект в памяти, на свои собственные данные.

Еще память для спана можно выделить в стеке через `stackalloc`, чтобы избежать лишней работы для сборщика мусора, но это уже другая история.

Comment: За счёт чего операции Span работают быстрее операций класса String?

Comment: @AlexeyLot во-первых, смотря какие операции, во-вторых, кто сказал что быстрее? В-третьих, над спанами и строками практически нет одинаковых операций. Основную разницу в подходе к использованию я выше уже рассказал: при работе со спанами можно избежать затрат на лишнее копирование данных в памяти с места на место.

Comment: Почему не происходит копирование, и в какой момент Remove в Вашем примере произведёт копирование?

Comment: @AlexayLot Remove создает новую строку, вообще любая строковая операция создает новую строку. Строка в C# неизменяемая, вообще никак, никогда. Любые "изменения" - это новые строки. А копирование в спан не происходит, потому что не происходит, и я знаю, как это работает, и вы изучайте. Всё на свете я не могу вам здесь в комментариях рассказать, читайте документацию.